# PHP Problems translating ASCII characters Function chr()

Tags: php, string, char, ascii, str-replace

I have a problem translating characters with the ascii table.
Example rare quotes like  “ or ” ’or‘

Part of the code

```
$txt = str_replace(chr(147), '"', $txt );    // left double quote
```

Someone can know what is due, it seems that you can not find the characters in the string

Comment: 147 is not double quote.

Comment: See the extended ASCII codes here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

This might help you solve any issues:

```
<?php
/* to avoid diamond shaped / garbled character output in browser
make the browser uses the correct encoding. Use a header.
*/
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
$chr = chr(147);
echo 'replacing ' . $chr . ' in target string.' . '<br />';
$txt = 'sometext' . $chr . 'andthensomemore' . $chr . 'andterminate';
echo 'BEFORE : ' . $txt . '<br />';
$txt = str_replace($chr, '"', $txt );
echo 'AFTER : ' . $txt;
?>
```